# Unable to add symbols with Functionalities using HTML CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have created a table with three columns. First column named as "Action",second column as "Question Subquestion/Text" and third column as "Sort order".
Also, I have added a functionality where we can drag and drop the rows.

My code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
        content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    table th,
    table td {
        width: 50px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 0.5px solid black;


    }

    .GFG {
        color: green;
    }

    .OK {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h2 class="GFG">Overall Experince</h2>
    <p class="OK">Drag and Drop table row</p>
    <table id="GFG">
        <tr>
            <td>Action</td>
            <th>Question Subquestion/Text</th>
            <th>Sort order</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Question1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Question2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Question3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Question4</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Question5</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Question6</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>7</td>
            <td>Question7</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Question8</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#GFG").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                dropOnEmpty: false,
                start: function (G, ui) {
                    ui.item.addClass("select");
                },
                stop: function (G, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("select");
                    $(this).find("tr").each(function (GFG) {
                        if (GFG > 0) {
                            $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(GFG);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now, I want to add three more symbols with functionalities for Delete, edit and view for "Action" column instead of numbers as mentioned in the code above.

The delete symbol will delete the whole set of the row and view and edit will open another page for edit and view.
I am new in this. Need help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with jQuery, consider if your app grows that you may benefit from a JS framework like React.

Be aware that the data will not persist - it needs to be saved to a database etc if you want to keep the state.

---

```html
<h2 class="GFG">Overall Experince</h2>
<p class="OK">Drag and Drop table row</p>
<table id="GFG"></table>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

CSS was unchanged

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // variable to hold the top row of the table
  const tableHeader = `
    <tr>
      <td>Action</td>
      <th>Question Subquestion/Text</th>
      <th>Sort order</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  `

  // initialise the list of questions - this may come from an API or external file
  let questions = [
      {id: 1, question: 'Question1' },
      {id: 2, question: 'Question2' },
      {id: 3, question: 'Question3' },
      {id: 4, question: 'Question4' },
      {id: 5, question: 'Question5' },
      {id: 6, question: 'Question6' },
      {id: 7, question: 'Question7' },
      {id: 8, question: 'Question8' },
    ]; 
  
  // the function to call to rebuild the table, it makes a list of rows from
  // the questions variables and prepends the top row to make the table
  // this will be slower the more rows you have 

  // the delete button is clicked via an on click event handler below
  // view and edit are simple links that open in new tabs, change the 
  // href attribute to what you want to show
  function buildTable() {
    const list = questions.map((q, index) => {
      return (`
          <tr>
            <td>${q.id}</td>
            <td>${q.question}</td>
            <td>${index+1}</td>
            <td class='delete' data-id='${q.id}'>Delete</td>
            <td class='view'><a target="_blank" href='/view/${q.id}'>View</a></td>
            <td class='edit'><a target="_blank" href='/edit/${q.id}'>Edit</a></td>
          </tr>
        `)
    })
    $('table#GFG').html(tableHeader + list.join(''))
  }
  
  // call the buildTable function to make the table when the page loads
  buildTable()
  
  // when the delete button is clicked, delete the row associated, then rebuild
  // the table when the row is deleted to show changes
  $('table#GFG').on('click', 'td.delete', (e) => { 
    questions = questions.filter(q => {
      if (q.id != e.target.dataset.id) { return true }
    })
    buildTable() 
  })
  
  // reset the questions to the default state and rebuild table 
  $('button#reset').on('click', () => {
    questions = [
      {id: 1, question: 'Question1' },
      {id: 2, question: 'Question2' },
      {id: 3, question: 'Question3' },
      {id: 4, question: 'Question4' },
      {id: 5, question: 'Question5' },
      {id: 6, question: 'Question6' },
      {id: 7, question: 'Question7' },
      {id: 8, question: 'Question8' },
    ]
    buildTable()
  })
});


// did not change this 
$(function () {
  $("#GFG").sortable({
    items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    start: function (G, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass("select");
    },
    stop: function (G, ui) {
      ui.item.removeClass("select");
      $(this).find("tr").each(function (GFG) {
        if (GFG > 0) {
          $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(GFG);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```